# The equal symbol can't aligned when using `alignat`

Tags: equations, align

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calrsfs,amsmath}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\pazocal}{OMS}{zplm}{m}{n}
\begin{document}
    \begin{alignat*}{2}
        &\pazocal{L} \left(f'(t)\right) &= \pazocal{L} \left(\sin(2t)\right)\\
        \iff& sF(s)-f(0)&= \dfrac{2}{s^2+4}\\
        \iff& sF(s)-0&= \dfrac{2}{s^2+4}\\
        \iff& F(s)&= \dfrac{2}{s(s^2+4)}.
    \end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

While I use `alignat`, why the equal symbol cannot align? How to fix it? Even though I have typed `&`.

[image]

Comment: you have specified 2 columns of equations so three `&` per row `right &= left & right &=left`  your F(s) column is in the _left_ aligned column, aligning towards the `\iff` not towards the following =

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place the F(s) column in the right aligned  (3rd) column of the alignment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calrsfs,amsmath}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\pazocal}{OMS}{zplm}{m}{n}
\begin{document}
    \begin{alignat*}{2}
        && \pazocal{L} (f'(t)) &= \pazocal{L} \sin(2t))\\
        \iff& & sF(s)-f(0)&= \frac{2}{s^2+4}\\
        \iff& & sF(s)-0&= \frac{2}{s^2+4}\\
        \iff& & F(s)&= \frac{2}{s(s^2+4)}.
    \end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```